# Can't login to domain account "you must be online the first time..."

Tags: windows-10, proxy, login, windows-domain

I've just installed windows 10 as a fresh install. I've configured the proxy settings for our organisation using a local account and the internet and local network seems to be working properly.

I have created a new user using my work email address and when I attempt to log in to it I get a long wait, followed by the error: `You must be online the first time to complete your account setup`. If I check the network connections from the login screen it appears to be connected, but it looks like it's timing out.

Do the proxy settings from a local account apply to all users? Is there a way to make sure they do?

Comment: Turns out I didn't actually need to do this. What I really should have been doing is adding my machine to the corporate domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy settings are by default user dependent.

To set a system proxy you could try to use [Netsh  and set the `WinHTTP` setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx).

`netsh winhttp import proxy` would import the proxy settings form the current user. While `netsh winhttp set proxy <proxy url>` would set it. To view the current settings just run `netsh winhttp dump`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I run this command from an admin prompt in the local user, don't I?

Comment: As that is probably the only option to currently access the system, yes.